# Questions regarding integrity of OPENVPN and SSH

Tags: windows-7, privacy-protection, privacy

I am a bit of noob, so I will explain my dilemma and would appreciate any advice to help me with it.

SSH  Tunnel connecting to Vps vs OpenVPN - which of these would be better suited for the following:

I am a private user operating from a home computer. I need to be able to surf the internet privately with no chance of my IP (even country location) being discovered by the site I am visiting.

(Several sites notorious trackers for this sort of stuff and are fairly draconian). I know that SSH will not display pages should my connection to the server drop out, that is to say my real ip will not be revealed in that event(or so I've been told) what about OpenVPN? Will other tracking methods such as flash cookies circumvent these setups(not sure how it all works and where things end up in those circumstances). Additionally are there any other ways 'diligent' sites can track even if one of the above setups are in place. Thankyou for your help

Comment: This isn't an answer, but if you're privacy conscious, then you should consider boycotting sites that have poor or non-existent privacy policies. You avoid being tracked, and you're not supporting companies that don't respect user privacy.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look into this: [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/). It is pretty much the most secure method available. The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_%28anonymity_network%29) might explain it better.

> Tor is an implementation of onion routing: The service works by relaying communications through a network of systems run by volunteers in various locations. Because the internet address of the sender and the recipient are not both readable at any step along the way (and in intermediate links in the chain, neither piece of information is readable), someone engaging in network traffic analysis and surveillance at any point along the line cannot directly identify which end system is communicating with which other. Furthermore, the recipient knows only the address of the last intermediate machine, not the sender. By keeping some of the network entry points hidden, Tor is also able to evade many internet censorship systems, even ones specifically targeting Tor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tor to remain anonymous to outside world. Also little utilities like hotspot shield also gives you the protection but tor is the best I have seen anywhere.
Tor with onion bundle comes with firefox extensions. This gives you the power of GUI without the hassle of setting up a proxy server.